# multiple lightboxes in one div

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox

how to create 2 lightboxes on another div? i created a sample code for lightbox but the problem is... i dont know how to create the second lightbox that will appear in the same page by clicking the link...

here's the css:

```
#fade{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.7;
    opacity:.70;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}
#light{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -100px;                 
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    background: #fff;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow:visible;
```

the script:

```
window.document.onkeydown = function (e)
{
    if (!e){
        e = event;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 27){
        lightbox_close();
    }
}
function lightbox_open(){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';  
}
function lightbox_close(){
    document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
}
```

then the body content:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="lightbox_open();">Open lightbox</a>
<div id="light"> lightbox1 <br>click to open lightbox2<br>
<a href=#>open</a>
</div>
<div id="fade" onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>
```

Comment: ...or is it on another div???

Comment: Forget it, the code isn't balanced anyway. You're missing an end div tag. As an aside, why aren't you using jQuery? Makes life a lot easier.

Comment: i edited it already but still doesnt work on fiddle. it is now working on mine... and dont know how to use query :/

Comment: jQuery's really easy to use, in fact - it's job is kind of all geared around making JS 'easier' (amongs many other cross-compatibility benefits etc.). Include a jQuery js file reference on your page then begin using jQuery syntax.